# Como pegar o valor vindo do Response

Tags: angular

Estou com um impasse na hora de pegar um JSON do meu retorno que não consigo ler ele de jeito algum já tentei de várias formas mostrarei abaixo como está o código agora e o que eu preciso fazer.

Meu método Component aonde está retornando o que eu quero.

```
  onSubmit(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario) {

    this.usuarioService.login(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario).subscribe(
       data => {
         if (data[0].res.status == 200) {

           this.usuario : Usuario = new Usuario(data[0].res._body.code, data[0].res._body.message)

           this.toastr.success("Teste", this.usuario.message);
         } else if (data[0].res.status == 500) {
           this.toastr.error("Teste", data.toString());
         }
         //data => this.data = data,
         //err  => this.erro = <any>err
       },
       error => {
         console.log(error);
       }
    );
  }
}
```

No meu console digitando data[0] saí assim, preciso pegar o Code e Message:

data[0]
{res: Response}
res
:
Response {_body: "{"code":0,"message":"Teste"}", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: Headers, …}
**proto**
:
Object

Ajeitei meu Service assim:

```
  login(loginUsuario: string, senhaUsuario: string): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/login/' + loginUsuario + '/senha/' + senhaUsuario)
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

Funcionou mas eu preciso que chega aqui no component o status:

```
  onSubmit(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario) {

    this.usuarioService.login(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario).subscribe(
       data => {
         //if (data[0].res.status == 200) {

           //this.usuario : Usuario = new Usuario(data[0].res._body.code, data[0].res._body.message)

           this.toastr.success("Teste", data.message);
         //} else if (data[0].res.status == 500) {
           //this.toastr.error("Teste", data.toString());
         //}
         //data => this.data = data,
         //err  => this.erro = <any>err
       },
       error => {
         console.log(error);
       }
    );
  }
```

Solução:

Meu Component:

```
  onSubmit(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario) {

    this.usuarioService.login(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario).subscribe(
      data => {

        if (data.status == 200) {
          this.data = data.json();
          this.toastr.success("Teste", this.data.message);
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Meu Service:

```
  login(loginUsuario: string, senhaUsuario: string): Observable<Response> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/login/' + loginUsuario + '/senha/' + senhaUsuario)
      .map((res:Response) => res)
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }
```

Comment: Do mesmo jeito que você está pegando o status.

Comment: não funciona amigo, dá undefined

Comment: se eu tento fazer isso dá undefined também, this.toastr.success("Teste", data[0].res._body.message);

Answer (score 1):

Faltou fazer o parse do JSON.

```
onSubmit(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario) {

this.usuarioService.login(loginUsuario, senhaUsuario)
  .map(data => data.json()) # <---- Transformar texto JSON em objeto!
  .subscribe(data => {
     if (data[0].res.status == 200) {

       this.usuario : Usuario = new Usuario(data[0].res._body.code, data[0].res._body.message)

       this.toastr.success("Teste", this.usuario.message);
     } else if (data[0].res.status == 500) {
       this.toastr.error("Teste", data.toString());
     }
     //data => this.data = data,
     //err  => this.erro = <any>err
   },
   error => {
     console.log(error);
   }
);
```

}

Comment: Eu editei como ficou agora, mais tem um porém eu preciso que chega o status no meu component pra mim fazer algumas regras, mais eu consegui pegar o que veio agora.

Comment: Consegui finalizar com sua dica, obrigado, postei a solução como ficou, agora posso dar continuidade com meu projeto :)